# MVC dialog validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui-dialog

Hi I am trying to validate one dropdown if was selected this way:

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 400,
            resizable: false,
            title: 'Add building',
            modal: true,
            open: function(event, ui) {

                $(this).load("@Url.Action("AddView",new {@ViewBag.from})");
            },
            buttons: {
                "Add": function () {
                    $("#LogOnForm").submit();
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
```

view

```
@model View.ViewModel.AddBuildingViewModel


@{Html.EnableClientValidation();}

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddBuilding", "HolidaysEvents", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "LogOnForm" }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ReqestFrom, new { @Value = @ViewBag.from })
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Building</legend>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Building.Name)
                    </div>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Building.Name)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Building.Name)
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Country
                </td>

                <td>
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Building.CountryId, new SelectList(Model.Countries, "Id", "Name"), "Choose Country... ", new { style = "height:35px"})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Building.CountryId)
                    </div>
                </td>

            </tr>

        </table>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Log On" style="display:none;" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

model

```
public class BuildingViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required.")]
        public int CountryId { get; set; }
    }
```

code

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddBuilding(AddBuildingViewModel buildingModel)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var modelError = new AddBuildingViewModel();
                modelError.Countries = countryRepository.GetCountries().Select(x => new CountryViewModel { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name }).ToList();
                return PartialView("AddView", modelError);
            }


            var model = new HolidaysEventsViewModel();
            buildingRepository.AddBuilding(buildingModel.Building.Name, buildingModel.Building.CountryId, WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);


            model.Buildings = buildingRepository.GetBuildings(WebSecurity.CurrentUserId).Select(x => new BuildingViewModel { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name }).ToList();
            model.Countries = countryRepository.GetCountries().Select(x => new CountryViewModel {Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name}).ToList();
            ViewBag.from = buildingModel.ReqestFrom;
            return View("Index", model);
        }
```

and the problem is that when user didn't select anything and validation works then dialog dissapears and instaed of it is just pure html page with validation message, how can I prevnt it and keep popup ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the modal dialog open you'll need to use AJAX. Instead of `$("#LogOnForm").submit()` you'll need to convert this to an [AJAX POST](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) submission and use its callback to replace the dialog's form with your partial view result.

Here's an outline of what to do:

First, you'll need to modify your dialog to accept the partial.

```
<div id="dialog">
    <div id="content">
       <!-- partial view inserted here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Now insert the partial view form into the dialog.

```
open: function(event, ui) {
    $("#content").load("@Url.Action("AddView",new {@ViewBag.from})");
}
```

AJAX post so you don't navigate away from this page.

```
"Add": function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/HolidayEvents/AddBuilding",
        type: "POST",
        data: $("#LogOnForm").serialize()
    })
    .done(function(partialResult) {
        // validation error OR success
        $("#content").html(partialResult);
    });
}
```

You may also need to prevent the default behavior on form submission because you handle the submission via AJAX.

```
$("#LogOnForm").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Your action returns a partial view to the `partialResult` in the callback.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddBuilding(AddBuildingViewModel buildingModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ...
        return PartialView("AddView", modelError);
    }

    ...
    return PartialView("SuccessView", model);
}
```

Since we used AJAX, the browser navigation to "Index" won't happen, so replace the dialog content with a success view. The success view will need a verify button so the user can close the dialog or navigate away to a new page..